# "Unable to parse API definition because of a malformed integration at path /price. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400;

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

The following code I put for x-amazon-apigateway-integration, please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks

```
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    httpMethod: post
    type: aws
    uri:
      Fn::Sub: 
        - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${FunctionArn}/invocations      
        - { FunctionArn: !GetAtt  PriceAPIFunction.Arn}
    responses:
      default:
        statusCode: '200'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `${AWS::Region}` substitution is not supported - only the function name can be substituted. see https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/79

Answer (score 2):

Hi [Mayank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9054751/mayank), [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3140406/andreas)

I was trying to create the CFT Deployment for the API and was getting the same error as **Unable to parse API definition because of a malformed integration at path /.**

I just figured out the solution as creating a **AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31** Template for the deployment.

You must write the CloudFormation Template as :-

 1. Add definition **Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31** in the beginning of the Template. 
 2. For the API Definition, must refer the **OpenApi** as **DefinitionBody**: with the **Transform** function, which will modulate the YAML accordingly.

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "MyRestAPI"    
      StageName: !Sub "dev"
      DefinitionBody:
        "Fn::Transform":
          Name: "AWS::Include"
          Parameters:
            Location: !Sub "s3://${TemporaryBucket}/openapi.yaml"
```